# Avoid plotting missing values on a line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I want a line plot to indicate if a piece of data is missing such as:
[image]

However, the code below fills the missing data, creating a potentially misleading chart:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load csv
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# plot a graph
g = sns.lineplot(x="Date", y="Data", data=df)
plt.show()
```

What should I change in my code to avoid filling missing values?

csv looks as following:

```
Date,Stagnation
01-07-03,
01-08-03,
01-09-03,
01-10-03,
01-11-03,
01-12-03,100
01-01-04,
01-02-04,
01-03-04,
01-04-04,
01-05-04,39
01-06-04,
01-07-04,
01-08-04,53
01-09-04,
01-10-04,
01-11-04,
01-12-04,
01-01-05,28
01-02-05,
01-03-05,
01-04-05,
01-05-05,
01-06-05,25
01-07-05,50
01-08-05,21
01-09-05,
01-10-05,
01-11-05,17
01-12-05,
01-01-06,16
01-02-06,14
01-03-06,21
01-04-06,
01-05-06,14
01-06-06,14
01-07-06,
01-08-06,
01-09-06,10
01-10-06,13
01-11-06,8
01-12-06,20
01-01-07,8
01-02-07,20
01-03-07,10
01-04-07,9
01-05-07,19
01-06-07,6
01-07-07,
01-08-07,11
01-09-07,17
01-10-07,12
01-11-07,13
01-12-07,17
01-01-08,11
01-02-08,8
01-03-08,9
01-04-08,21
01-05-08,8
01-06-08,8
01-07-08,14
01-08-08,14
01-09-08,19
01-10-08,27
01-11-08,7
01-12-08,16
01-01-09,25
01-02-09,17
01-03-09,9
01-04-09,14
01-05-09,14
01-06-09,3
01-07-09,14
01-08-09,5
01-09-09,8
01-10-09,13
01-11-09,10
01-12-09,10
01-01-10,8
01-02-10,12
01-03-10,12
01-04-10,15
01-05-10,13
01-06-10,5
01-07-10,6
01-08-10,7
01-09-10,13
01-10-10,19
01-11-10,19
01-12-10,13
01-01-11,11
01-02-11,11
01-03-11,15
01-04-11,9
01-05-11,14
01-06-11,7
01-07-11,9
01-08-11,11
01-09-11,24
01-10-11,14
01-11-11,17
01-12-11,14
01-01-12,10
01-02-12,13
01-03-12,12
01-04-12,12
01-05-12,12
01-06-12,9
01-07-12,7
01-08-12,9
01-09-12,15
01-10-12,13
01-11-12,25
01-12-12,13
01-01-13,13
01-02-13,15
01-03-13,23
01-04-13,22
01-05-13,14
01-06-13,13
01-07-13,20
01-08-13,17
01-09-13,27
01-10-13,15
01-11-13,16
01-12-13,18
01-01-14,18
01-02-14,19
01-03-14,14
01-04-14,14
01-05-14,10
01-06-14,11
01-07-14,8
01-08-14,18
01-09-14,16
01-10-14,26
01-11-14,35
01-12-14,15
01-01-15,14
01-02-15,16
01-03-15,13
01-04-15,12
01-05-15,12
01-06-15,9
01-07-15,10
01-08-15,11
01-09-15,11
01-10-15,13
01-11-15,13
01-12-15,10
01-01-16,12
01-02-16,12
01-03-16,13
01-04-16,13
01-05-16,12
01-06-16,7
01-07-16,6
01-08-16,13
01-09-16,15
01-10-16,13
01-11-16,12
01-12-16,14
01-01-17,11
01-02-17,11
01-03-17,10
01-04-17,11
01-05-17,7
01-06-17,8
01-07-17,10
01-08-17,12
01-09-17,13
01-10-17,14
01-11-17,15
01-12-17,13
01-01-18,13
01-02-18,16
01-03-18,12
01-04-18,14
01-05-18,12
01-06-18,8
01-07-18,8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since the data is already in a `pandas.DataFrame`, the easiest solution is to plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.

  - Incidentally, `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# load the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('d:/data/hh.ru_stack.csv')

# convert the date column to a datetime.date
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%y').dt.date

# plot with markers
ax = df.plot(x='Date', marker='.', figsize=(9, 6))

# set the ticks for every year if desired
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
```

[image]

- Alternatively, plot with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) or [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax.plot('Date', 'Stagnation', '.-', data=df)
ax.legend()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Make example data
s = """2018-01-01
2018-01-02,100
2018-01-03,105
2018-01-04
2018-01-05,95
2018-01-06,90
2018-01-07,80
2018-01-08
2018-01-09"""
df = pd.DataFrame([row.split(",") for row in s.split("\n")], columns=["Date", "Data"])
df = df.replace("", np.nan)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Data"] = df["Data"].astype(float)
```

Three options:

1) Use `pandas` or `matplotlib`.

2) If you need `seaborn`: not what it's for but for regular dates like yours you can use `pointplot` out of the box.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

plot = sns.pointplot(
    ax=ax,
    data=df, x="Date", y="Data"
)

ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

3) If you need `seaborn` and you need `lineplot`: I've looked at the source code and it looks like `lineplot` drops nans from the DataFrame before plotting. So unfortunately it's not possible to do it properly. You could use some advanced hackery though and use the `hue` argument to put the separate sections in separate buckets. We number the sections using the occurrences of nans.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

plot = sns.lineplot(
    ax=ax,
    data=df, x="Date", y="Data",
    hue=df["Data"].isna().cumsum(), palette=["black"]*sum(df["Data"].isna()), legend=False, markers=True
)
ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Unfortunately the markers argument appears to be broken currently so you'll need to fix it if you want to see dates that have nans on either side.

Answer (score 7):

Try setting NaN values to `np.inf` -- Seaborn doesn't draw those points, and doesn't connect the points before with points after.

Comment: Incorrect, experiment for yourself with below code (by adding/removing the inf part):
```
x = np.arange(10.);
y = (-1) ** x;
y[5] = np.nan;
y[5] = np.inf;
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y});
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y');
```

Comment: Downvoting. Seaborn does connect the values.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Denziloe answer:

there are three options:

1) Use `pandas` or `matplotlib`.

2) If you need `seaborn`: not what it's for but for regular dates like above`pointplot` can use out of the box.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

plot = sns.pointplot(
    ax=ax,
    data=df, x="Date", y="Data"
)

ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

graph built on data from the question will look as below:
[image]

Pros:

- easy to implement
- an outlier in the data which is surrounded by `None` **will** be easy to notice on the graph

Cons:

- it takes a long time to generate such a graph (compared to `lineplot`)
- when there are many points it becomes hard to read such graphs

3) If you need `seaborn` and you need `lineplot`: 
`hue` argument can be used to put the separate sections in separate buckets. We number the sections using the occurrences of nans.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

plot = sns.lineplot(
    ax=ax
    , data=df, x="Date", y="Data"
    , hue=df["Data"].isna().cumsum()
    , palette=["blue"]*sum(df["Data"].isna())
    , legend=False, markers=True
)

ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

Pros:

- lineplot
- easy to read
- generated faster than point plot

Cons:

- an outlier in the data which is surrounded by `None` **will not** be drawn on the chart

The graph will look as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set **markers** parameter to empty string. It will trigger a UserWarning but have the desired effect.

```py
sns.pointplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Data', markers='')
```

Answer (score 0):

A small change in the source code can also help you out:

```
diff --git a/seaborn/relational.py b/seaborn/relational.py
index ff0701c7..f4ab8cd9 100644
--- a/seaborn/relational.py
+++ b/seaborn/relational.py
@@ -273,7 +265,7 @@ class _LinePlotter(_RelationalPlotter):
 
         # Loop over the semantic subsets and add to the plot
         grouping_vars = "hue", "size", "style"
-        for sub_vars, sub_data in self.iter_data(grouping_vars, from_comp_data=True):
+        for sub_vars, sub_data in self.iter_data(grouping_vars, from_comp_data=True, dropna=False):
 
             if self.sort:
                 sort_vars = ["units", orient, other]
```

Found here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3351#issuecomment-1530086862

For future reference, there is an open issue: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1552

But could not be fixed at the moment because of "some snags".