# Piecewise python/seaborn plot with segmented lines?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm trying to use seaborn to make lineplots of a few variables, but I'm trying to make sure that lines are segmented when not continuous. Example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan], [2, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 1], [np.nan, 2], [4, np.nan], [6, np.nan]],
                   columns=['cat', 'dog'])
display(df)
plt.plot(df['cat'])
plt.plot(df['dog'])
```

[image]
[image]

When I try to do the plotting in seaborn I get:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

[image]

Or using the dataframe format that I prefer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'cat'],[2, 'cat'], [np.nan, np.nan],
                   [1, 'dog'], [2, 'dog'], [4, 'cat'], [6, 'cat']],
                   columns=['value', 'type'])
display(df)
sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='value', hue='type')
```

[image]
[image]

SO... Is there a way to do a seaborn plot that looks piecewise like the first plot that was created using matplotlib/pyplot? Can it be done using the 2nd dataframe format with a value column and a category column?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098537/seaborn-avoid-plotting-missing-values-line-plot).

Comment: Why did you not try to plot from `pandas` and `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

1. drop rows where every value is `NAN`
2. replace remaining `NaN` with `np.inf`
3. plot with `seaborn.lineplot`